# What is "comeback of late?" and age of "I'm OK, You're OK."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From "Were Dinosaurs Dumb?" by Stephen Jay Gould:

> Dinosaurs have been making a strong comeback of late, in this age of "I'm OK, You're OK."

I know the meaning of every word, but still the meaning eludes me. What is comeback of late? and age of "I'm OK, You're OK."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"of late" means "lately", "recently".

"I'm OK, you're OK" is basically a reference to a culture of tolerance and diversity which is supposed to have its roots in the hippie culture of 1960s California. (I note that this likely comes from an exam preparation piece---this meaning is very difficult to guess for a non-native speaker.) Gould is using it mildly ironically, to mean that dinosaurs are getting a more favourable portayal from scientists nowadays---they are not being 'discriminated against' any more. The gentle irony comes from the fact that you can't really discriminate against a dinosaur, because:

- They've been dead for millions of years
- We usually think of discrimination as applying to human beings

Comment: _Making a comeback_ = returning to popularity.